# How to upgrade from magento-1.5.1.0

Tags: upgrade, magento-1.9.2.1, version, magento-1.5.1

**How to Upgrade Magento 1.5.1.0 to latest version (1.X)?**

Comment: For the last Magento 1 version, see linked duplicate. Magento 2 is a new product, there is no upgrade path from Magento 1.x to Magento 2.x - only data migration is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade Roadmap

1. take a backup of current database and current 1.5.1.0 code.
2. download latest magento from the http://www.magentocommerce.com/download
3. remove all folders and files from your 1.5.1.0 code (but you should have backup somewhere) and place all folders and files from the 1.x.
4. now from your 1.5.1.0 merge your following folders into the 1.x

   - Community app/code/community
   - Local app/code/local
   - Media
   - your theme or package (app/design/frontend/default/ or app/design/frontend/)
   - custom folders from Skin (both for adminhtml and frontend).
   - copy your custom xml files from app/etc/modules/ to current app/etc/modules/
   - any custom admin theme folder from adminhtml/default/yourtheme.
   - copy your custom folders from adminhtml/default/default/ (1.5.1.0) to adminhtml/default/default/ (1.x).
   - custom js files if any from app/js/.
5. now go to app/etc/local.xml.Edit database details their.put your database username and password and database name.
6. now check the site.it done.